# Hide tabs when opening a new one if you haven't change anything

Tags: ide, sublimetext, atom-editor

I am using Atom for first time.

Sublime has a great functionality which consists in:

You open a file, you just see the content and don't change anything.
Then when you open a new file, as you haven't change anything in the last one, then the new file will take the place of the last one.

Did you get it ? is there a way to do that with Atom ?

Comment: This isn't natively implemented, but it's one of the thinks I like about Sublime. I think I'll build a package. Also, you should post this in their github as a feature issue ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is implemented as "Preview Tabs" in the bundled ["tabs" package](https://atom.io/packages/tabs) in Atom. Go to Settings > Packages > search for "tabs" > click its "Settings" button. Scroll down to tick the "Use Preview Tabs" checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since **Atom 1.6** this behavior is built in Atom itself, and does not rely on the tabs package or external ones. **The "Use Preview Tabs" (as shown in accepted answer) is even not available anymore**.

It is now called "Pending Pane Items" and is described in [Atom 1.6 release announcement](http://blog.atom.io/2016/03/17/atom-1-6-and-1-7-beta.html).

> Sometimes, it can be useful to take a peek at the contents of a file
>   without opening it in a dedicated tab. For those instances, you want
>   pending pane items.

Differences between now so called "Pending Pane Items" and ex "Preview tabs" have been also discussed on Atom's Discuss platform: [Pending panes vs. preview tabs](https://discuss.atom.io/t/pending-panes-vs-preview-tabs/26756).

Pending pane items are now enabled by default, and there is no need to activate anything to use it. For those that do not like this behavior, it can be disabled from "Core Settings" by unchecking "Allow Pending Pane Items" setting:

[image]