# Atom setting to open files in the same window?

Tags: configuration, atom-editor

I'm just trying out Atom for the first time and I find it bothersome that Atom keeps opening a new window for each file I click on - I'd prefer that it defaulted to opening each file in the same window.

I'm hoping for something along the lines of `"open_files_in_new_window" : false,` in Sublime.  Unfortunately, all the google results I'm seeing just lament that this toggle is not immediately obvious.

Comment: Since Atom 1.6 this functionality is built and enabled by default: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977001/hide-tabs-when-opening-a-new-one-if-you-havent-change-anything/36140867#36140867

Comment: any update for 2019? this is driving me crazy with the new version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to *Settings > Packages*, look for the **tabs** package. In the settings for this package, choose "**use preview Tabs**".

Comment: Atom 1.6.2 clean install Win7 x64. There is no such setting.

Comment: This has been replaced by "pending panes": http://blog.atom.io/2016/03/17/atom-1-6-and-1-7-beta.html

Answer (score 10):

In your terminal you can type `atom -a <filename||folder>` and the file(s) will open within the same atom window.

Answer (score 2):

Per the `atom -h` command, one should open files with `-n=false` or `--new-window=false` argument passed so that they are opened in an existing window, e.g.

```
atom -n=false ~/Desktop/test.py
```

One could make `atom -n=false` an alias of `atom` in the `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` file, or one could edit the corresponding file in `/home/<your username>/.local/share/applications` so that the command it invokes is, for instance, `/usr/lib/atom/atom -n=false %F`.

Comment: Just had the same problem and found this solution at https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/5138#issuecomment-83137672, so, seeing other answers don't mention this, I thought I'd share it.

Answer (score -1):

Just in the editor window, drag the open tab by mouse onto the window you need.[image]